# is there a way to search a huggingface Repository for a specific filename?

Tags: python, search, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I'd like to search a huggingface repository for a specific filename, without having to clone it first as it is a rather large repo with thousands of files.

I couldn't find a way to do it with the web interface, I installed the *python* package `huggingface_hub` and looked into `huggingface_hub.Repository` and `huggingface_hub.HfFileSystem` without success.

If somehow a search query isn't possible, may be retrieving the list of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use [`huggingface_hub.list_files_info(repo)`](https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub/blob/4f1e4bbb28b58ffbc2588d2c549c6be0d083bac8/src/huggingface_hub/hf_api.py#L1892-L1901) to get a list of file information objects for a repository; I'm using that [here](https://github.com/akx/ggify/blob/422def513a2630ee708f3d5a0e6f6602ba55de4b/ggify.py#L88-L93) in my `ggify` project.

---